# How to run a batch script completely and automatically on event such as sleep/hibernate and shutdown event using task scheduler?

Tags: windows, networking, scripting, batch-file, task-scheduler

I have written a batch script to perform some folder synchronizing task. I have scheduled the script to execute using task scheduler on events such as sleep/hibernate(kernel power event id 42) and shutdown (user32 event id 1074). The script is initiating on these events but it get stopped in between and computer goes to sleep/hibernate/shutdown and afterwards when I turned on the computer the script resumes. I want the script to complete first and then the computer should go off.

can someone provide me the solution to this or any alternate way to achieve the task.

This is the screenshot of my script [test.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFENR.png)

I have modified my script like this [Modified test.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSWbm.png)

but the problem doesn't solved [log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxCFf.png)

see the script started at 17:21(when I clicked start -> power -> sleep)
but ended at 17:43 (when I turned on the pc)

Comment: Show us the script commands you are using for sleep/wake. Typically when starting these, the Power Plan needs to be changed to prevent the computer from sleeping during the task.

Comment: i have added the screenshot of the script. I'm not using any command to make the system sleep/hibernate/shutdown. 
The requirement is that I want the script should start when there is an user initiated event such as sleep/shutdown/hibernate I have used task scheduler for that but the problem is that the script is getting stopped in between and resumes afterwards when the system get turned on.

Comment: Did you open the Power control panel and confirm the expected plan was selected?

Comment: yes high performance mode was selected. I have checked it by printing it in logfile

Answer (score 0):

In broad strokes, use `powercfg.exe /s` to set the Power Plan to the "high performance" plan before you run your script. This can be as a separate cmd file, as you can specify multiple files in the task definition. After your script completes, run powercfg.exe again to set the power saving Power Plan as active. Run `powercfg.exe /l` to list the available plans, and obtain the plan ids to use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options

Comment: I have modified the script and added it details in the question above. Please see if there is any solution to it.